# How can i convert all purpose flour to bread flour?

Tags: baking, substitutions

Sometime I want to cook something that requires bread flour, but bread flour is unavailable. I have all purpose flour. How can I convert it to bread flour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between bread flour and all purpose flour is that bread flour has a higher protein content. While bread flour has 12 to 14 percent protein, all purpose has 8 to 11 percent protein.  The reality is that you probably won't notice the difference without a side by side comparison, so, if all you have is all purpose, just use that.  If you want to increase the protein level of your flour, you can do that by adding vital wheat gluten.  However, I am guessing that if you don't have access to bread flour, you will probably not have access to vital wheat gluten.  In the event that you do, I found the following conversion: Measure out 1 cup all-purpose flour (4 1/2 ounces or 129 grams).  Remove 1 1/2 teaspoons (1/8 ounce or 4 grams). Add 1 1/2 teaspoons vital wheat gluten (1/8 ounce or 5 grams).  Whisk or sift to combine.